# Using a string variable from a text box to search an Xml file using Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm new to using XPath and would appreciate any assistance. I want to search an XML file similar to the one below using a variable entered in a text box that is part of a login page. The variable is to be used to validate the correct user. I am having difficulty coming up with the correct expression to do this. Below is an example of a sample Xml file that I have been using.I am programming in Visual Basic.

```
<Log>
    <customer>
        <customerid>12345</customerid>
        <password>Pass1</password>
        <login>00001</login>
        <image>Ducati1.jpg</image>
        <fname>Julie</fname>
        <lname>James</lname>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <customerid>23456</customerid>
        <password>Pass2</password>
        <login>00002</login>
        <image>Ducati2.jpg</image>
        <fname>Bob</fname>
        <lname>Barnett</lname>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <customerid>345678</customerid>
        <password>Pass3</password>
        <login>00003</login>
        <image>Ducati3.jpg</image>
        <fname>Callum</fname>
        <lname>Claw</lname>
    </customer>
</Log>
```

The code that I have tried is as follows:
 Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

```
    Dim pass As String
    Dim user As String

    pass = lblPassword.Text
    user = lbluser.Text


    Dim doc As New XmlDocument
    Dim nodes As XmlNodeList


    doc.Load(Server.MapPath("App_Data\Customer.xml"))
    nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//customer[password = "pass")

    For Each node In nodes

        TextBox3.Text = node.SelectSingleNode("customerid").InnerText

    Next

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this language you use vbs or vba,
but I think you can try this xpath

```
 //customer[descendant::password[text()= 'Pass2']]
```

tested here http://www.xpathtester.com/obj/bbcf034f-1b3f-4a23-8e99-8f2b57044b46

And give attention to singe and double quotes when you put it here doc.SelectNodes()

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following XPATH expression, it fetches `customer` whose `password` is *pass2* then it takes `customerid` .

```
//customer[password='pass2']/customerid
```

I suspect more than one user can have same `password`. Better to take `customerid` using `login` , as mentioned below:

```
 //customer[login='00002']/customerid
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The issue is that the login is "dynamic" which is why I created a variable to store the login in. Troubles arise when I search for the string in the Xpath expression i.e. //customer[login='pass']/customerid